# What happens if the timer reaches 0 in the hotel?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

On the level in the Royal Hotel, there is a part where there are "Snowmen bombs".  There is a timer that supposedly is counting down to a detonation on December 31 (in-game time).

What happens if this timer reaches 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a spoiler (if you haven't passed this part yet)

> The bomb will detonate no matter what you do. When you defuse the bomb, it will skip to 15 seconds to detonation, and Batman will jump out the window to a helicopter, seeing the building explode in the background

Answer (score 2):

Nothing exciting happens.

If you do decide to wait for a week, the clock will stop at one hour. Neither Batman nor Joker will comment on this.